# How to update Database Modification at the Entity from Entity Model?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I've designed the `entity model` which has been mapped from the `Sql server database`. Later on, I've updated the `Identity column` in a particular table in database then I've done `Update Model from`Database.
Unfortunatly, It wasn't updated in my `Entity Model`. What should I do to sort  it out ?

Any help or suggestion are greatly appreciated !!!

Comment: Drop and re-add the table to your model? I know EF is fussy with changes to identities and existing columns

Comment: It's annoying me to re-add the table. Is there any other possibilities ?

Answer (score 1):

Manually edit the EDMX either in Designer or Xml view, whichever is your preference.

Comment: During the 1st time It has generated automatically. My point is the update also should be happen automatically. Am i right ?

Comment: As Koenyn correctly pointed out there are scenarios in which the Update function won't be able to update your model. One such scenario is key column changes. If you were to just add a table, relationship or column you would be in good shape. If you'd rather not edit the EDMX then you can always kill it and regen it completely as you did the first time.

Comment: Seems very bad designer Issue. Rob Epstein thanks for your suggestion. I planned to edit manually.